# Caching a non changing frequently read file in python

Tags: python, caching

Okay folks lemme illustrate, I've this

```
def get_config_file(file='scrapers_conf.json'):
    """
    Load the default .json config file
    """
    return json.load(open(file))
```

and this function is called a lot, This will be on a server and every request will trigger this function at least 5 times, I've multiple scrapers running, each one is on the following shape.

I removed helper methods for convenience, the problem is, each scraper should have it's own request headers, payload, ... or use the default ones that lie in `scrapers_conf.json`

```
class Scraper(threading.Thread): # init is overriden and has set .conf
    def run(self):
        self.get()

    def get(self):
        # logic
```

The problem is that I'm getting the headers like

```
class Scraper(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.get()

    def get(self):
        headers = self.conf.get('headers') or get_config_file().get('headers')
```

so as you see, each single instance on each single request calls the get_config_file() function which I don't think is optimal in my case. I know about `lru_cache` but I don't think it's the optimal solution (correct me please!)

The config files are small, `os.sys.getsizeof` reports under 1 KB.

I'm thinking of just leaving it as is considering that reading a 1 KB ain't a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've totally forgot about `@functools.cached_property`

```
@cached_property
def get_config_file(file='scrapers_conf.json'):
    """
    Load the default .json config file
    """
    return json.load(open(file))
```

Answer (score 0):

`lru_cache(maxsize=None)` sounds like the right way to do this; the `maxsize=None` makes it faster by turning off the LRU machinery.

The other way would be to call `get_config_file()` at the beginning of the program (in `__init__`, `get`, or in the place that instantiates the class), assign it to an attribute on each Scraper class and then always refer to `self.config` (or whatever). That has the advantage that you can skip reading the config file in unit tests — you can pass a test config directly into the class.

In this case, since the class already has a `self.conf`, it might be best to update that dictionary with the values from the file, rather than referring to two places in each of the methods.

Comment: thanks, but I found a better solution for global use